# Let $f(z) =e^\frac1z + \frac{1}{z-1}$ and determine what kind of singularities (removable, essential or pole) occur at $z=0$ and $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, singularity

Let $f(z) =e^\frac1z + \frac{1}{z-1}$.

I need to determine what kind of singularities (removable, essential or pole) occur at $z=0$ and $z=1$.

My understanding of them is that at $z=0$: $$f(z) =e^\frac1z - 1$$
Which would make this an essential singularity in the same way that it is for $f(z) =e^\frac1z$, correct?

And for the singularity at $z=1$, this leaves us with: $$f(z) =e+\frac{1}{z-1}$$
Which would make this singularity a pole, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, but for the wrong reasons. You have $f(z)=e^{1/z}+\frac1{z-1}$ everywhere; in particular, it is not true that, near $0$, $f(z)=e^{1/z}-1$. However, near $0$ you have$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^0\frac{z^n}{(-n)!}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n,$$and therefore $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Near $1$, $e^{1/z}$ has a Taylor series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$, and therefore$$f(z)=(z-1)^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n.$$It follows from this that $f$ has a pole of order $1$ at $1$.

Comment: Your explanation for this is much appreciated. I believe you would also be able to assist me in my understanding of the first part of this question, finding the Laurent Series for $f(z)$ about zero in the regions $0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$. I initially posted my attempt on a separate question with this one but was asked to split it into two by moderators. Can you kindly verify if my working is correct for the two cases?

Comment: It's done now.${}$